# chef client ssl error while synchronising cookbooks

Tags: chef-infra, cookbook

I got the following error when I run my chef client. Any idea how to fix it. It appears to increasing the timeout may work. Because it is taking a while to get the cookbooks from the server. Where to increase the timeout?

```
    penSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server session ticket A
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:800:in `connect'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:800:in `block in connect'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:55:in `timeout'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:100:in `timeout'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:800:in `connect'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:756:in `do_start'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:745:in `start'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1285:in `request'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/net_http_ext.rb:51:in `request'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.10.4/lib/chef/http/basic_client.rb:64:in `request'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.10.4/lib/chef/http.rb:249:in `block in send_http_request'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.10.4/lib/chef/http.rb:291:in `retrying_http_errors'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.10.4/lib/chef/http.rb:245:in `send_http_request'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.10.4/lib/chef/http.rb:165:in `streaming_request'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.10.4/lib/chef/rest.rb:166:in `streaming_request'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.10.4/lib/chef/rest.rb:104:in `get'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.10.4/lib/chef/cookbook/synchronizer.rb:202:in `download_file'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.10.4/lib/chef/cookbook/synchronizer.rb:180:in `sync_file_in_cookbook'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.10.4/lib/chef/cookbook/synchronizer.rb:147:in `block (2 levels) in sync_cookbook'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.10.4/lib/chef/cookbook/synchronizer.rb:145:in `each'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.10.4/lib/chef/cookbook/synchronizer.rb:145:in `block in sync_cookbook'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.10.4/lib/chef/cookbook/synchronizer.rb:143:in `each'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.10.4/lib/chef/cookbook/synchronizer.rb:143:in `sync_cookbook'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.10.4/lib/chef/cookbook/synchronizer.rb:105:in `block in sync_cookbooks'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.10.4/lib/chef/cookbook/synchronizer.rb:104:in `each'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.10.4/lib/chef/cookbook/synchronizer.rb:104:in `sync_cookbooks'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.10.4/lib/chef/policy_builder/expand_node_object.rb:181:in `sync_cookbooks'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.10.4/lib/chef/policy_builder/expand_node_object.rb:68:in `setup_run_context'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.10.4/lib/chef/client.rb:252:in `setup_run_context'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.10.4/lib/chef/client.rb:413:in `do_run'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.10.4/lib/chef/client.rb:200:in `block in run'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.10.4/lib/chef/client.rb:194:in `fork'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.10.4/lib/chef/client.rb:194:in `run'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.10.4/lib/chef/application.rb:215:in `run_chef_client'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.10.4/lib/chef/application/client.rb:314:in `block in run_application'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.10.4/lib/chef/application/client.rb:306:in `loop'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.10.4/lib/chef/application/client.rb:306:in `run_application'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.10.4/lib/chef/application.rb:66:in `run'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.10.4/bin/chef-client:26:in `<top (required)>'
```

Comment: Sorry, this question lacks many information. Does it work with other nodes? Can you access the Chef server web interface through your browser? Did it ever work? Are you using opening source chef server? Did you adjust the configuration of your chef server in any way e.g. `ssl_verify_mode`?

Comment: Other clients works perfect. we have one particular client returns this error after downloading couple of cookbooks from the chef server. I dont think so the problem lies in Chef-server. I have not touched any ssl related config in the chef server, al are running default config. Yes, we are running a open source chef server. I am not what made you to think on the chef server angle. All my error happens in the client as my title clear says "chef client emits this error"

Comment: But it is not clear that it works with other clients - how should I know? So given your information: Does the config of that particular client differ from the others, e.g. the mentioned `ssl_verify_mode` or do the suggestions by [sethvargo](http://stackoverflow.com/users/365738/sethvargo) help?

Answer (score 0):

That error (which you've cut off partially) results when Ruby can't verify the SSL certificates when connecting to a remote service (the Chef Server in this case). You either need to turn off SSL verification or add your Open Source Chef Server's certificate to your local bundle.

Comment: Seth, It is not a partial error. It just the content I got in chef-stacktrace. And this happens in halfway while synchronising the cookbooks. Do you think any other error would help you find the issue?